# How get last date in month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have parameter `YEAR` and `MONTH`, for example  `2021`  and  `9`

How do I get the last date of that month, in that year?

For example, with the values mentioned before, I should receive:

```
30.09.2021.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not [literraly](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions072.htm) ?

```
select LAST_DAY(SYSDATE) from dual
```

with your parameters

```
select LAST_DAY(to_date('01'||:month||:year,'ddmmyyyy')) from dual;
```

Comment: Tnx,  I'm also add lpad  ---->  Select LAST_DAY(to_date('01'||LPAD(:MONTH, 2, '0')||:YEAR,'dd.mm.yyyy')) from dual

Comment: Use `TO_CHAR(:month, 'FM00')` to get from one digit 9 to the two-digit string '09'.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner   Yes, I'm add lpad .  Select LAST_DAY(to_date('01'||LPAD(:MONTH, 2, '0')||:YEAR,'dd.mm.yyyy')) from dual

Comment: yep, if the month paramater consis onl yof one character you must `lpad` it with zero @Pointer